# How to make “Paste as Plain Text” button selected by default?

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

When pasting a text in PhpStorm 2023.3:

[image]

Is there a way to make “Paste as Plain Text” button selected by default ?

Comment: No, there is none. But you can use shortcuts for that: CTRL + Shift + V